# Scrolling down on click

Tags: html, css

When I click on my image (it is a down arrow) it scrolls down smoothly just like I want, but it seems like it doesn't scroll far enough.

My scroll goes down to 90% of my header but still shows the 10% remaining.

How is that possible?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-scrollTo').on('click', function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    var speed = 700;
    $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: $(page).offset().top }, speed );
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="global">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li id="acceuil"><a href="index.html">ACCEUIL</a></li>
          <li id="tarif"><a href="tarif.html">TARIF</a></li>
          <li id="livraison"><a href="livraison.html">LIVRAISON</a></li>
          <li id="suivi"><a href="suivi.html">SUIVI</a></li>
          <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="down"><a class="js-scrollTo" href="#down"><img src="http://etu07.heff-technique.be/bicyolis/down-arrow.gif" alt="arrow" width="70" height="35"></a></div>
      </nav> 
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="presentationimg">
        <div id="pic1"><p>Le service de livraison<br> de lettres et colis<br> ultra-rapide à Bruxelles</p>
          <img src="http://etu07.heff-technique.be/bicyolis/cyclingv2.gif" alt="picto1" width="500"></div><br>
        <div id="pic2"><p>Nos livraisons sont effectuées<br> dans les 19 communes de Bruxelles<br> en moins de 24 heures</p>
          <img src="http://etu07.heff-technique.be/bicyolis/vespa.gif" alt="picto2" width="500"></div>
        <div id="pic3"><p>Nous utilisons uniquement<br> des vélos, vélos électriques<br> et scooter électriques</p>
          <img src="http://etu07.heff-technique.be/bicyolis/bicycle-elec.gif" alt="picto3" width="500"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="slider">
        <p>Livraison de lettres et colis à domicile</p>
        <p>Sans pollution<br>Sans émission de CO2<br> et à petit prix!</p>
      </div>  
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: use this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is telling the window to scroll down to the position of the ID `#down`, which happens to be the arrow button.

In other words, currently clicking the arrow button will scroll the page down to the top of that arrow button.

To fix this, remove the `id="down"` surrounding your button link, and move it to the `<main>` element (so it becomes `<main id="down">`).

Per your request, a more detailed explanation of what's happening:

1. User clicks this link: `<a class="js-scrollTo" href="#down">...</a>`
2. JavaScript sets var page based on href of your link: `var page = $(this).attr('href')`, so now `page = #down`
3. JavaScript scrolls to the top of `#down`: `$(page).offset().top`

Comment: Just to understand, may I ask you which line calls for the scroll down to id #down in my JavaScript?

Comment: @raggz I added an explanation to my answer.